# Uploading the file to sharepoint and automatically check in the the file after upload using WebClient

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Uploading the file to SharePoint by using webclient PUT method its getting uploaded but checked out in my name. How we can checked in the file automatically?

Please suggest me how to fix the issue.
Below is the code which upload the file to SharePoint.

```
public void UploadToSharepoint()
        {
         
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                var site = string.Empty;
                var serviceAccountUsername = string.Empty;
                var serviceAccountPassword = string.Empty;
                var serviceAccountDomain = string.Empty;

                var documentToUpload = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.DocumentToUpload].ToString();
                var documentLibrary = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.documentLibrary].ToString();

                int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
                int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
               
                var targetDocumentName = year + "_" + month + "_ABCD.xlsx";
              
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(documentToUpload))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found", documentToUpload);

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                 
                    site = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.SiteUrl].ToString();

                    serviceAccountUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.ServiceAccountUsername].ToString();
                    serviceAccountPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.ServiceAccountPassword].ToString();
                    serviceAccountDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppConstants.ServiceAccountDomain].ToString();

                    if (!client.UseDefaultCredentials)
                    {
                        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential
                        {
                            Domain = serviceAccountDomain,
                            UserName = serviceAccountUsername,
                            Password = serviceAccountPassword
                        };

                        client.Credentials = networkCredential;
                    }

                    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(documentToUpload);
                    var uri = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", site, documentLibrary, targetDocumentName));

                    client.UploadData(uri, "PUT", bytes);
                }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
```

Comment: [How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints - Working with files by using REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx#Files)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some required fields, to them you have to set before check in the file.

to check in
use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ListItem.File.CheckIn(...) Function